# Force user to reload assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Is there a way to make a user reload assets automatically?

(I am forever asking clients to "reload the cache" after a new deployment but there must be a better, less obtrusive method?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to "reload the cache" in Rails 3 since assets name contains now a digest of the content so if you even change a char the digest changes and user request the new, updated asset.

Comment: In that case, please explain why the following occurs: we make a change to the CSS, we recompile the assets, and then the user sees a mess.  We get them to reload their cache and it then works fine.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? BTW it's strange because from the user point of view when you change something in your CSS he have to get a completely different CSS file with a different name (so it's not present in its browser's cache)...

Comment: Using version 3.1.1. When I view the source on the deployed app it loads CSS like this: "<link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />" - there is no integer in there as per I have previously seen - is this a configuration option?

Comment: Yes I've seen an option for the digest, check if the config.assets.digest option is true in your config/environments/production.rb

Comment: It appears that this is false for some reason - thanks - will investigate now